# How do I present a modal view upon an option in UIActionSheet being tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, storyboard

I have my main view controller, and tapping a button brings up an action sheet. I want one of the options tapped there to bring up an action sheet. I can't seem to figure it out, however, despite all my searching.

I have the following code:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Text"]) {
        AddTextViewController *addTextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addTextViewController"];        
    }
```

Now that I instantiated the view controller, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line right after you instantiate it.

```
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Text"]) {
    AddTextViewController *addTextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addTextViewController"];        
    [self presentViewController:addTextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Note**

You can also create a custom segue in the Storyboard that presents your view, then instead of instantiating and presenting you can just perform your custom segue. Both work the same.

**Storyboard Method**

First click your segue in Storyboards, then give it an identifier in the info panel.

[image: Storyboard Segue Settings]

Then you can replace your code with this and it should trigger the segue from your Storyboard.

```
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Text"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"infoSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: How would I do the later solution in my storyboard?

Comment: And for the first I get this error: `No visible @interface for 'RootViewController' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:'`

Comment: @DougSmith That's because `presentViewController:animated:` doesn't exist, it's actually `presentViewController:animated:completion:` I've edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: oops sorry for the typo. Thanks @0x7fffffff

Comment: @DougSmith I added information on using the Storyboard + Segue method.

Comment: I get this error for the first solution: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "2Pv-MD-gdY-view-bDF-TR-G6E" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: How do I make a segue from a UIActionSheet in the storyboard?

Comment: You don't make a Segue from a UIActionSheet. You make an IBAction in your code then show the segue.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: As far as I've known you make segues from ctrl-dragging from a button to a viewcontroller in the storyboard. How do I do this for an action sheet? Or how do I create the segue in general?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26389/discussion-between-doug-smith-and-ryan-poolos)