# I have a UITableViewController that presents a UIActionSheet, how do I make an action sheet option bring up a modal view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, storyboard, uitableview

I'm having a lot of trouble with this, and I can't seem to find an answer specifically to this situation.

I have a UITableViewController that has a button, that upon being clicked presents a UIActionSheet with a few options. I want one of the options to bring up another view controller that I have already present in my storyboard, ready to be shown.

The UIActionSheet is fully implemented, with the `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` as well, I just don't know what to do within it.

I tried having this within it:

```
NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Text"]) {
    AddTextViewController *addTextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addTextViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:addTextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

But I get an error saying: `No visible @interface for 'RootViewController' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:` so that's not working either.

What exactly am I supposed to be doing here?

Comment: How many times do you want to ask this same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method as `presentViewController:animated:`. The method is actually `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

So change:

```
[self presentViewController:addTextViewController animated:YES];
```

to:

```
[self presentViewController:addTextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Pass in an actual completion block if desired.

Comment: Funny, that's exactly what I said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478786/how-do-i-present-a-modal-view-upon-an-option-in-uiactionsheet-being-tapped#comment21908800_15478839

Comment: I get this error for the first solution: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "2Pv-MD-gdY-view-bDF-TR-G6E" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'